# Set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is a countable set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show that the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is countable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200389/show-that-the-set-of-all-finite-subsets-of-mathbbn-is-countable)

How can I prove in a proper way that the "set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ (the set of natural numbers) is a countable set"?
Please help me with this.Thank you.

Comment: Grazel: I think you'll find some nice answers to your question by clicking on the link immediately above.

Comment: Also see: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263677/how-many-subsets-of-mathbbn-have-the-same-cardinality-as-mathbbn

Comment: Since $\mathbb{N}$ is a countably infinite set, it may help to see as well http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27096/the-cardinality-of-the-set-of-all-finite-subsets-of-an-infinite-set?rq=1.

Answer (score 2):

Let $S$ be the set of all finite subsets of $N$. It is easy to verify that the function $f:S\rightarrow N$ that sends $A$ to $\sum_{a\in A} 2^{a}$ is a bijection

Answer (score 1):

For an approach with cardinal numbers:

- The set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is the union over $n$ of the set of all subsets of size $n$.
- The set of all subsets of size $n$ is no bigger than the set of all ordered tuples of length $n$.

Therefore, the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ has cardinality less than or equal to:

$$ \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} |\mathbb{N}|^i = \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} |\mathbb{N}| = |\mathbb{N}| \cdot |\mathbb{N}| = |\mathbb{N}|$$