# Number of one-to-one Function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

How many one-to-one functions are there from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$, Where $\mathbb{N}$ is the set of Natural numbers?

Comment: Continuum $\mathfrak{c}$.

Answer (score 4):

We can count these as follows: any injective function $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is uniquely determined by its image (which is an infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$), and the order induced on its image via the ordering of the domain (that is, we say $f(1)\le f(2)$, etc). So what we are really asking is how many images are possible, i.e. how many infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ are there (covered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263677/how-many-subsets-of-mathbbn-have-the-same-cardinality-as-mathbbn)) and how many permutations on the image there are (covered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300444/bijection-between-the-reals-and-the-set-of-permutations-of-the-natural-numbers)).

Both of these answers are $\mathbb{R}$, so the answer to your question is the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$, which has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. the continuum as Sangchul Lee noted in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\Bbb N$ has only countably many finite subsets,

Also Note that by Cantor's Theorem $P( \Bbb N)$  has uncountably many elements.

Thus $\Bbb N$ must have uncountably many countably infinite subsets, because otherwise $P( \Bbb N)$ will be countable.

Thus there are uncountably many bijections between $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb N

Thus there are uncountably many one-one functions between $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb N$